# Showing that an absolute value function is not differentiable

Tags: calculus

I have a function that looks as follows $|x^2 - 2x|$ and i would need to show that it's not differentiable at $x = 2$. So my approach was just the usual to find out if the difference quotients are the same from both sides. So i decided to break up the function as a piecewise in order to find the difference quotients, but i ended up with something like this.

$$     f(x) = \begin{cases} 
          x^2-2x & x> 2 \\
          -(x^2 -2x) & x< 2 
       \end{cases}
    $$

and from here i got

$$\lim_{x\to 2-} \frac{-(x^2-2x)}{x-2} = \lim_{x\to 2-} \frac{-x^2+2x}{x-2}$$

but this will just end up being undefined, so what am I not seeing here?

Comment: It is not undefined. Factor the numerator. Next, compute the limit from the right and see it will be a different value, this the limit will not exist.

Comment: Alright now i just feel stupid for not seeing something like this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are on the right track.

$$f^\prime_{\uparrow} = \lim_{x\to 2-} \frac{-(x^2-2x)}{x-2} = -2$$

$$f^\prime_{\downarrow}  = \lim_{x\to 2+} \frac{x^2-2x}{x-2}=2$$

Since the lower and upper limits are not equal, the derivative does not exist at $x=2$.